# Is it possible to setup a user while building a Debian package even when that user does not exist on the build system?

Tags: ubuntu, users, packaging

I have a package I like to build locally. Some of the files in the package are to be installed on a system where a given user is created first. Those files should be owned by that user.

For example, say I have a user "foo" on my server and I create a package with a file such as `/usr/share/foo/protected.file` which has permissions `u=r` (i.e. only that user can read that file).

What I'd like to do in my `debian/rules` file is to setup that file like so:

```
override_dh_fixperms:
    dh_fixperms
    ...
    chmod 400 debian/foo/usr/share/foo/protected.file
    chown foo:foo debian/foo/usr/share/foo/protected.file
    ...
```

My problem is that the computer I use to build the package does not have a user named "foo" so that `chown` fails. I would like to not create a "foo" user on that computer.

Is there a way to do that in the build process (i.e. I know I could hack the resulting .tar file, but I don't want to do that).

---

I use the following command to run my local build:

```
dpkg-buildpackage -us -uc
```

Comment: IIRC the mysql server packages will create a mysql user if one doesn't already exist, and then install the directories and files owned by that user.  Perhaps looking at those preinstall/postinstall scripts could give you ideas of how to do this in your own package.

Comment: Read `man adduser useradd`. The former is probably the right tool.

Comment: I already add the user on the target server. I don't think you understand what I'm asking about. I'm not looking at creating the user. I'm looking at doing a `chown` on the computer where I do the build of the package without having to create the user.

Comment: What's the reason you are trying to chown files/dirs to a nonexistent user on the build machine?  What is the problem you're trying to solve by doing that?

Comment: When installing, the tarball gets extracted and the user could be changed to the one in the tarball and then later in the postinst if I "fix" the issue there. I guess if the user is root:root in the tarball found in the package, it's not that bad since it doesn't make the file unsecure. It may be unaccessible for a little while for that user (a form of race condition).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Technically*, you can construct your package in any way you want. As far as `.deb` files are concerned, all that’s expected in the final stage of package construction is that `debian/rules binary` leaves a valid `.deb` file with the right name in the parent directory. So you could override `dh_builddeb` to create the tarball with files owned by a non-existent user.

However Debian packages involving non-standard users don’t do this: they handle file ownership in their `postinst`. They usually also handle user creation there: if the user doesn’t exist, they create it before running `chown`. This ensures that the package is installable regardless of pre-existing users.

The race condition you mention in a comment shouldn’t matter in practice: if `dpkg -i` succeeds, the file will have the right ownership before `dpkg -i` completes; if it fails, the package should be considered unusuable anyway.

Comment: Oh, right, while you run an upgrade, you generally stop using the package processes/services (you even stop the service if currently running). So the potential race condition would not be an issue in nearly all cases.

Answer (score 1):

When you `chown` you are not changing the owner to a name, you are changing it to a number (the UID the name is mapped to).

You could require that the user is created with a specific UID (and GID) on the target system, and change your command to use those numerics; e.g.

```
chown 9876:9876 debian/foo/usr/share/foo/protected.file
```

Comment: Oh good point. I'll never have that many users on one machine that such high ID would clash with anything.